# Flexslider2 not resizing on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design, flexslider

I have a responsive slider which is supposed to show 1 item per slide at less than 600px width and 3 per slide above that. (as per http://flexslider.woothemes.com/dynamic-carousel-min-max.html) It works if window is loaded at those sizes, but does not work if window is resized (the items per slide don't change). I get an error "Cannot read property 'vars' of undefined" I've tried replacing "$" with jQuery in front of the var but the entire thing breaks at that point.

```
    jQuery(window).load(function() {

  // store the slider in a local variable
  var $window = $(window),
      flexslider;

  // tiny helper function to add breakpoints
  function getGridSize() {
    return (window.innerWidth < 600) ? 1 :
           (window.innerWidth < 900) ? 3 : 3;
  }

  $(function() {
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
  });

  jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: false,
    itemWidth: 290,
    itemMargin: 0,
 minItems: getGridSize(), // use function to pull in initial value
      maxItems: getGridSize() // use function to pull in initial value
    });
 // check grid size on resize event
  jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    var gridSize = getGridSize();

    flexslider.vars.minItems = gridSize;
    flexslider.vars.maxItems = gridSize;
  });
  });

}(document));
```